# Adaptive Card Date Format dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: adaptive-cards

I'm trying to format an Adaptive card date to dd/MM/yyyy
using this data:

```
{
    "Due_Date": "2020-09-20T06:08:00Z",
}
```

I tried these formats:

```
           {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Due Date: {{DATE(${$root.Due_Date}, COMPACT)}} "
            },
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text":  "Due Date: ${formatDateTime(Due_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}"
            }
```

and I got this render from AC Studio:
[image: Adaptive Card]

When I use the designer I get this result:
[image]

Using:

```
          {
                    "title": "Date Only",
                    "value": "{{DATE(${start}, COMPACT)}}"
                },
```

This is the problem I am having with my card rendering as MM/dd/yyyy.

So AC Viewer is using my locale but the browser is using some other locale.
Even more interesting look at the time. that time has had 12 hours added on to it!

I'd like to tell this card that to use my locale, can I configure the SDK to use my locale. Why is the browser not using my locale?

Using AC Studio My locale is EN-AU , I don't think it's using it at all :-(
Rendered using Javascript SDK and AC Studio in VS Code, same in AC Designer
TIA. all suggestions welcome

Comment: OMG that's a terrible example as it shows the date in the format I want :-(, how confusing!

Answer (score 0):

There's various ways to format dates on AdaptiveCards when using Adaptive Expressions.

There's a nice sample card here: https://www.madewithcards.io/cards/adaptive-expressions-playing-with-dates

```
[{
"title": "Date Only",
"value": "${formatDateTime(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
}, {
"title": "Time Only",
"value": "${formatDateTime(start, 'HH:mm')}"
}, {
"title": "Date and Time",
"value": "${formatDateTime(start, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')}"
}, {
"title": "Long Date",
"value": "${formatDateTime(start, 'dddd dd. MMMM yyyy')}"
}, {
"title": "Short Date",
"value": "${formatDateTime(start, 'MM MMMM y')}"
}, {
"title": "Short Date with Time",
"value": "${formatDateTime(start, 'dd.MM.yy - hh:mm')}"
}]
```

Comment: And as a sidenote, AC viewer is quite outdatded. Try this one: https://www.madewithcards.io/studio/ supports all the latest stuff

Comment: Thanks Tim, that is the sample that I was using and I  am using Studio, not Viewer. Here in Australia we are old-fashioned and write our dates dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Tim. I had another look and it's a locale issue, your Viewer gets the local locale, the browser, doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted this as an Issue for the Javascript SDK https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/4842

Comment: This is now an Adaptive Expression issue https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/2864